# SELECT Agents Who Have Not Been Evaluated (by week)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to pull list of agents that have not been Evaluated (Scored) in the past week. I'm getting the Agent_Name, but when checking list of Evaluations, their names are appearing in the Evaluation list.

```
select agent.firstname + ' ' + agent.lastname Agent_Name
from dbo.agent agent
left outer join dbo.crr crr
on agent.id = crr.agentfk
left outer join dbo.evaluation eval
on crr.id = eval.crrfk
where eval.crrfk is null 
and crr.localtime >= Dateadd(Day, Datediff(Day, 0, Dateadd(D, -7,     Current_Timestamp)), 0);
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the date from `crr` and not `evaluation`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thanks for your help.  I believe you're right.  I do need date from evaluation table and not crr.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the condition on `crr` to the `on` clause:

```
select agent.firstname + ' ' + agent.lastname Agent_Name
from dbo.agent agent left outer join
     dbo.crr crr
     on agent.id = crr.agentfk and
        crr.localtime >= Dateadd(Day, Datediff(Day, 0, Dateadd(D, -7,     Current_Timestamp)), 0) left outer join
     dbo.evaluation eval
     on crr.id = eval.crrfk
where eval.crrfk is null ;
```

I'm not sure why you need the `evaluation` table, if the data is in `crr`.  I mean, this should do the same thing (assuming you are using the right date):

```
select (a.firstname + ' ' + a.lastname) as Agent_Name
from dbo.agent a left outer join
     dbo.crr
     on a.id = crr.agentfk and
        crr.localtime >= Dateadd(Day, Datediff(Day, 0, Dateadd(D, -7,     Current_Timestamp)), 0) 
where crr.id is null ;
```